# Aborting Bootloader process

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus

I wanted to superroot my Samsung Galaxy Nexus I9250 and then I got to the bootloader and couldn't solve my problem.  The problem was that the driver installed on my computer was an unknown device and wouldn't read my phone or something (code 43).

How can i abort the **bootloader** process and just my phone get back to **factory** settings?

Comment: So are you basically just looking to reboot your device?

Comment: well now I am, just so I can use it and superroot it later

Comment: Hold the power button for a few seconds or remove the battery.  What does this have to do with factory settings?

Comment: well doesn't the bootloader erase everything?  and wouldnt removing the battery destroy information or something?  If removing the battery is a safe way or returning the device back then ill do that.  and the holding down the power button won't work for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're literally sitting at the bootloader screen, the volume buttons will scroll between boot options and the power button will select. Simply use the volume buttons until it has "Start" selected and then press the power button to select it. This will boot your device normally.

If for some reason it's stuck at the bootloader and won't accept input, removing the battery should be fine provided that you aren't in the middle of executing a fastboot command of some kind. Note that if you're getting a response of `<waiting for device>` from fastboot that it is **not** doing anything on the phone's side. That means that it cannot communicate with the phone, and as such the bootloader itself is basically idle at that point.

Since you noted in a comment that you were concerned about the bootloader erasing things: the bootloader process in and of itself doesn't do this. The purpose of the bootloader is to allow you to boot into various different modes of the phone (such as recovery and a normal boot). In the PC world a bootloader is often used to dual boot two different operating systems, with the bootloader menu being what allows a user to select which OS they want. The only time that your data will be erased is when you execute the `fastboot oem unlock` or `fastboot oem lock` commands or if you explicitly erase a partition in some other way (`fastboot erase`, for example). Simply booting into your bootloader does not affect your data in any way.